# No output when I use std::cout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8")); in C++

Tags: c++, locale, number-formatting, punctuation, numberformatter

I am trying to give my output number to have punctuation when they're over 1,000.
I searched some functions that uses this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct numberPunctuations : numpunct<char> {
    string do_grouping() const {
        return "\03";
    }
};


int main()
{
    locale loc (cout.getloc(), new numberPunctuations);
    cout.imbue(loc);
    
    cout<<1000;

    return 0;
}
```

and it works but I saw a shorter code but I can't get it to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;



int main() 
{
    cout<<fixed<< setprecision(2); // decimal place

    // comma separator
    locale loc ("en_US.UTF-8");
    cout.imbue(loc);

    //cout.imbue(locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

    // test data
    cout<<123425 + 342346<<'\n';
    cout<<123.523456;

    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to run it there's no post (no output) but when I use vim and a online compiler (OnlineGDB) it works. I like the second code because it's shorter, is there a way to make it work?

PS: The IDE that I use is clion (student version) and VS code.

Comment: Are you on Windows? The locale `std_name` only has a few names that are standardized (or maybe only one, `C`). `en_US.UTF-8` is not standardized unfortunately.

Comment: yes I am on windows, well I tried C.UTF-8 it also doesn't work when I remove UTF-8 there's an output but the punctuations doesn't work also

Comment: on windows the locale is just [`.UTF8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-160#utf-8-support), it doesn't have `C` in the name. This is because the `C` locale is always the system's ANSI code page so it's literally asking for something and then asking for something else in the same go.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to hardcode the locale? Wouldn't picking up the user's locale and setting that be an option?

Comment: @TedLyngmo if they just did `".UTF8"` it would be utf-8 with the user's locale.

Comment: I did try to check what my current locale is in clion using this code
and the output is always C except when I changed it to null

edit: I tried to post my code here but it doesn't format into a block thingy.

Comment: `en_US.utf8` doesn't exist so it'll use the default, which is `C`. Try checking the user's locale instead. `std::locale loc(""); std::cout << loc.name() << '\n';`

Comment: I checked the user's locale and it's C and when I try to change it, it doesn't change and the output is still C but by changing it to null it works.

Comment: @TedLyngmo please see the link in my comment above, the locale `"en_us.utf8"` absolutely exists. So that statement is provably false by Microsoft's own documentation. The locale `"C.utf8"` does not however.

Comment: @Mgetz Aha, my bad! Sorry for the misinformation

Comment: It seems to be a pretty recent addition though (from Windows 10 build 17134).  @Mr.purp: What windows version are you running?

Comment: Windows 10 
Version 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1237)
@TedLyngmo
I really appreciate the help :D tho if things don't work out I can just use the first code.

Comment: @Mr.purp yeah, but it's boring for someone with a different locale to get `.` where `,` is expected :-)

Answer (score 0):

The *user preferred* locale can be selected with an empty locale name:

```
locale loc("");
```

On Windows, a named locale name may look like `"en-US"` or `"English_United States.1254"`. For more information, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/locale-names-languages-and-country-region-strings?view=msvc-160).

Comment: They can still use UTF-8 with the user's preferred locale by just setting a locale of [`".UTF8"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-160#utf-8-support)

Comment: ok I'll try thanks :D

Comment: update: still no post when I run my test data

Comment: @Mr.purp `"en-US"` works perfectly well on mine, gives output with the comma as the thousands separator and the period as the decimal separator, as is customary in the US. "de-DE" switches them around as it should.